# Pass dict with non string keywords to function in kwargs

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments

I work with library that has function with signature `f(*args, **kwargs)`.
I need to pass python dict in kwargs argument, but dict contains not strings in keywords

```
f(**{1: 2, 3: 4})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() keywords must be strings
```

How can I get around this without editing the function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Non-string keyword arguments are simply not allowed, so there is no general solution to this problem. Your specific example can be fixed by converting the keys of your `dict` to strings:

```
>>> kwargs = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> f(**{str(k): v for k, v in kwargs.items()})
```

Comment: I think this is the best that can be done really. Keyword arguments must be strings, Hence the `TypeError`.

Comment: @Will -- I think that what is best really depends on the dicts you're passing in.  Consider the dictionary `d = { '1':1, 1:3 }` here.

Comment: I suppose the _true_ best solution would be to re-write the function to either accept only string keywords or to have an optional dict argument to pass the dictionary in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is filter out the non-string arguments in your dict:

```
kwargs_new = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if isinstance(k,str)}
```

The reason is because keyword arguments *must* be strings.  Otherwise, what would they unpack to on the other side?

Alternatively, you could convert your non-string keys to strings, but you run the risk of overwriting keys:

```
kwargs_new = {str(k):v for k,v in d.items()}
```

-- Consider what would happen if you started with:

```
d = { '1':1, 1:3 }
```

Comment: This is Python 3, so there is no `basestring`.

Comment: @larsmans -- Fair enough.  I didn't look at the tags that closely.