# Passing dicts with non-string keywords

Tags: python, dictionary

It appears that one cannot pass dicts with non-string keywords to functions in Python. (I see this has been brought up before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981810/pass-dict-with-non-string-keywords-to-function-in-kwargs))

However, before coming up with some sort of convoluted solution to my problem, I figured I would ask the experts and see if there is something I'm missing. **Unfortunately, I cannot change this paradigm easily without significant re-factoring, as a previous author never anticipated this type of action** (this is a very simple example).

I have objects called `services` that can perform actions on `nodes`. Some `nodes` require different `service` configurations. Instead of a `service` instance per `node`, I have one instance of each `service`, which I then combine with configuration parameters per `node`. The `service` and it's corresponding configuration parameters are stored in a `dict`.

Both the `node` along with its `services` and their corresponding configuration parameters are passed to a function (`setupServices`) which then processes everything. This function must be able to call functions which are part of the `service` object. Unfortunately, this fails with the error:

```
TypeError: setupServices() keywords must be strings
```

If you're wondering what's passing it as `**nodeServices` instead of just `nodeServices`, it is the code segment below (value would be `nodeServices` in this case). I'm hesitant to make this code specific for an individual case, as it acts as a backbone for many other things.

```
if type( value ) is list:
    result = f( *value )
elif type( value ) is dict:
    result = f( **value )
else:
    result = f( value )
results[ name ] = result
return result
```

Are there any other ways I can accomplish this with minimal modification?

```
"A node can be associated with many services"
class Node(object):
    pass

"""Setup services routine (outside of the node due to an existing design choice)
   I could rewrite, but this would go against the existing author's paradigms"""
def setupServices ( node, **nodeServices ):
    for object, objOverrides in nodeServices.items():
        "do something with the service object"

"2 simple services that can be perform actions on nodes"
class serviceA(object):
    pass

class serviceB(object):
    pass

"instantiate an object of each service"
a = serviceA()
b = serviceB()

"Create a node, assign it two services with override flags"
node = Node()
nodeServices = {}
nodeServices[a] = { 'opt1' : True }
nodeServices[b] = { 'opt2' : False }

"Pass the node, and the node's services for setup"
setupServices ( node, **nodeServices )
```

Comment: Is `objects.items()` supposed to be `nodeServices.items()`?

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks, fixed that and a few other things.

Comment: I can't see how your example with the `if type(value) is dict` stuff can be working with the API you described.  That calls `f` with only one argument, whereas your `setupServices` accepts two.  For the same reason, it wouldn't make sense to pass arguments with `*list` in most cases.  It could only be working just by pure luck of never happening to pass a list with more than one argument, etc.  If the API you inherited is really that fragile, you should probably knuckle down and rewrite it, because it looks like it could cause more serious problems later.

Comment: @BrenBarn I agree -- this happens to be a contribution to an open source project, so I'm not in complete control here. You're also right that the example I provided doesn't match this context exactly -- it was difficult to construct an example which wasn't a mile long. I've implemented a simple check to see if any keyword in the dict passed contains a non-string keyword and if it does, I change how the dict is passed.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to change that is to change `setupServices` so it no longer accepts keyword arguments, but just a dict of options.  That is, change its definition to:

```
def setupServices (node, nodeServices):
```

(removing the `**`).  You can then call it with `setupServices(node, nodeServices)`.

The only downside to this is that you must pass in a dict, and cannot pass literal keyword arguments.  With the keyword-argument setup, you could call `setupServices(node, opt1=True)`, but without keyword arguments, if you wanted to specify that option "inline" you would have to do `setupServices(node, {'opt1': True})`, passing in a literal dict.  However, if you're always programmatically creating a dict of options anyway and then passing it with `**`, this downside won't really matter.  It only matters if you actually have code that is passing literal keyword arguments like `setupServices(node, foo=bar)`.

As the answer in the question you linked to says, there is no way to make functions accept non-string keyword arguments.  So there is no way you can get `foo(**nodeServices)` to work when the keys of `nodeServices` aren't strings.  (Given that, it's a little hard to understand how this scheme could have ever worked, since in your example it seems like `setupServices` was always expecting a dict whose keys were service objects, which means passing them as keyword arguments never could have worked.)

Comment: I would use this solution, but unfortunately there is a function 10,000 feet up that makes the decision to call `setupServices(node, **nodeServices)` if it detects that `nodeServices` is a `dict`. Is there anyway to detect that `nodeServices` is a dict with non-string keywords, and then make this second call instead?

Comment: @BSchlinker: You can just iterate over the keys and see if all are strings: `if all(isinstance(k, basestring) for k in nodeServices)`.  However, not sure if that's really what you want based on what you said.  You don't want to make it sometimes make the call with `**` and sometimes without.  Just make it never use `**` when passing `nodeServices`.

Comment: Note that the `dict()` function is an exception to this string only keywords rule in Python 2, but this has been fixed in Python 3.

Comment: I've added some details on how the call is being made and why it's difficult to change that